# Convert dataframe from vertical to horizontal

Tags: r, dataframe, vertical-alignment, horizontal-line

I already checked many questions and I don't seem to find the suitable answer.

I have this df

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:10,y=11:20)
```

the output

```
    x  y
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   6 16
7   7 17
8   8 18
9   9 19
10 10 20
```

I just wish the output to be:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
x 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
y 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `t()` like below

```
> data.frame(t(df), check.names = FALSE)
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
x  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
y 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: ah yeah I forgot about this function thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A transpose should do it

```
setNames(data.frame(t(df)), df[,"x"])
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
x  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
y 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```